# Freeing Natives Objects

Tags: java, c++, memory, java-native-interface, wrapper

How the best way to detect the GC call for a Java Object?

I'm build a Java Wrapper for a C++ code, and I need to free **memory allocated in C++ code** every time GC is called.

I saw some solutions, but none of then satisfied me.

One of the was:

```
Object obj = null;
try{
    obj = new Object();
    // do things
} finally {
   if(obj != null){
      obj.freeCObjects();
   }
}
```

Comment: _I need to free memory every time GC is called_ Isn't that what GC is already doing?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm talking about freeing memory from a C++ wrapper Objects.

Comment: What was wrong with the other solutions? What kind of improvement are you looking for?

Comment: The JDK does not provide a hook into the GC.

Comment: @Keppil I want to discuss the benefits of all and know other solutions. I'm building an API, so I want to choose the best way to my solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know! That's the reason I'm asking here if anyone has another solution.

Comment: @Victor - what is the life-cycle of these C++ objects? Are they somehow related to Java objects that will get collected? If yes, then [phantom references](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj#PhantomReferences) are one solution.

Comment: Also: if you've seen other solutions, you should list them and explain why they didn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the [finalize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) method that is available on `java.lang.Object`.

```
It is called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines 
that there are no more references to the object.
```

In general, it is best to avoid finalizers because the JVM doesn't guarantee that `finalize()` is ever called on any object, however when there is a need to clean up native (usually non-Java) resources, a finalizer can be useful.

Here is a simple example:

```
    Object obj = new Object() {
        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("finalize object");
            super.finalize();
        }
    };
```

The finalizer *may* be invoked by garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reliable way to do this with just the garbage collector. The usual approach (employed, for example, by the SWT UI toolkit, which uses native components) is to require clients to call a `dispose` or `destroy` method on the object.

Comment: That's a good approach. I'm already doing that. But there is no other solution?

Comment: @Victor No other reliable solution, no. Finalizers aren't guaranteed to run ever, and even if they do run, the JVM might not get around to them for a very long time, especially if the JVM doesn't see much Java heap space being used by the objects (since they're mostly in other address space). Furthermore, while it's fine to provide a "rescue" close operation in a finalizer, making a point of this in documentation will inevitably lead to lazy programmers' failing to close resources properly and running into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely you want to free memory every time a GC is run.  Must more likely you want to free memory to unused objects when the GC is run.

You can do this by providing a wrapper with an implementation for finalize() which frees the resource.  When the wrapper is discarded, you can clean up the resources.  If you really want this to disappear on every GC you can hold a WeakReference to the wrapper.

BTW The OpenJDK/Oracle HotSpot JVM has another, more light weight mechanism for freeing resources.  This involves using a Cleaner object which is not added to the finalization queue (meaning it can be freed faster)  See the direct ByteBuffer which has a Cleaner as an example.